Do the methods 'putFile' and 'putFileAs' from Storage facade temporarily save the file to laravel?
I couldn't find a clear answer to this. But do the methods 'putFile' and 'putFileAs' temporarily save the file to laravel before uploading to S3? I'm trying to stream large file uploads from our frontend to laravel to S3 (without using presignedurls). I preferably do not want the file to download to laravel before uploading to s3. I'm wondering if 'putFile' or 'putFileAs' can just stream the file to S3? Would it be enough to call Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs($dir, $file, $filename) to accomplish this?

In PHP when you upload a file it will be saved in a temporary location $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], then it will be deleted after the script has done executing.

@aceraven777 Is there a way to directly upload the file to s3 without having to download from angular to s3 and then again from laravel to s3?

What's the purpose of this question? Because the proper way is, you upload the file from angular to laravel, then laravel to s3. Do you want to upload from angular to s3 directly?

For my requirements, I can't upload from angular to s3. The file uploads can be pretty big so I'm trying to see if streaming would reduce the time to upload.

Have you tried searching in google? How about this solution: https://medium.com/@hassanrazadev/how-to-upload-large-files-in-laravel-web-application-bde34da8b242

Well my main question was more so whether or not putFile and putFileAs handles steaming.
